# Saving multiple jpgs to sd card

Tags: android, save, jpeg, counter, parse-platform

I am downloading images from  [parse.com](http://www.parse.com/). I never know the amount of images I will have so I am using a counter to retrieve them. For some reason, my counter gets to 5, and downloads an image 5 times. In my storage, I only have one image. Here is my code:

```
String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
int i = 0;
```

Retrieve images:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("fightGallery");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> parseObjects, com.parse.ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {

                int size = parseObjects.size();
                Log.d("query size", "size is " + size + " int i is " + i);
                while (i < size) {
                    ParseFile fileObject = parseObjects.get(i).getParseFile("image");

                    fileObject.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(byte[] bytes, ParseException e) {
                            if (e == null) {
                                Log.d("Data", "We have data successfully " +i);

                                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                                saveImagesInSdCard(bmp, i);


                            } else {
                                Log.d("ERROR: ", "" + e.getMessage());
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    i++;
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("ERROR:", "" + e.getMessage());
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
```

This is my `saveImagesInSdCard()`

```
 private void saveImagesInSdCard(Bitmap bmp, int i) {


    File myDir = new File(root + "/clash_images");
    myDir.mkdirs();
    String fname = "Image";
    File file = new File(myDir, fname+i+".jpg");
   // if (file.exists()) file.delete();
    Log.d("IMAGE", "SAVED " +fname + i);

    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Here is my logcat showing all my `Log.d`

```
08-07 12:54:45.586  10403-10403/com.codealchemist.clashmma D/query size: size is 5 int i is 0
08-07 12:54:46.407  10403-10403/com.codealchemist.clashmma D/Data: We have data successfully 5
08-07 12:54:46.527  10403-10403/com.codealchemist.clashmma D/IMAGE: SAVED Image5
08-07 12:54:48.079  10403-10403/com.codealchemist.clashmma I/Choreographer: Skipped 100 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-07 12:54:48.089  10403-10403/com.codealchemist.clashmma D/Data: We have data successfully 5
08-07 12:54:48.199  10403-10405/com.codealchemist.clashmma D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 8524K, 20% free 38799K/48391K, paused 13ms+4ms, total 60ms
08-07 12:54:48.199  10403-10403/com.codealchemist.clashmma D/IMAGE: SAVED Image5
08-07 12:54:50.131  10403-10403/com.codealchemist.clashmma D/Data: We have data successfully 5
08-07 12:54:50.181  10403-10403/com.codealchemist.clashmma D/IMAGE: SAVED Image5
08-07 12:54:51.242  10403-10403/com.codealchemist.clashmma D/Data: We have data successfully 5
08-07 12:54:51.312  10403-10403/com.codealchemist.clashmma D/IMAGE: SAVED Image5
08-07 12:54:53.494  10403-10403/com.codealchemist.clashmma I/Choreographer: Skipped 323 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

As you can see, in my logcat, my `i` never changes from 5. How do I  structure this to download all 5 images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that the `GetDataCallback` was taking too long. So my counter `i` was getting to 5 before it could set the file name. So my solution was just adding another counter in my `GetDataCallback`. Comment if you need to see the code.

Answer (score 1):

When your `GetDataCallback` is executed after the file is downloaded, the loop has run 5 times and as such the value of `i` will be 5 every time.

Comment: I can see that from my logcat. But why is is not running my `GetDataCallback` 5 times, so I can download all 5 images?

Comment: I understand that my `getdatacallback` is only ran on the 5th loop. My question Hector, is how do I get my data call back to run all 5 times?

Comment: It is running five times, as you can see in your logs. The problem lies with using a variable that is being mutated before the callbacks are executed.

Comment: Isn't the `i++` being "mutated" after my callback?

Comment: Am I misplacing my `while` loop?

Comment: You're kicking off five asynchronous network operations, and the i is being mutated before they come back with your file's data. Your while loop is not misplaced - you just shouldn't expect the callback to capture the value of i that you expect. If you use a different filename when writing your file's to disk, you should end up with five different files. As it is now, you're overwriting your one file, four times, with different files.

Comment: OK, I see... So my solution is too what? Cause I'm creating a different file each time, but inside my callback. So do I need to create the file names outside of my callback?

Comment: Do you know the solution? Or is parse not capable of this?

Comment: Just make sure to use a different filename for each file. You can generate a random filename inside the callback block and use that.